# Extract non unique values from array

Tags: ruby

I can remove unique values from an array:

```
array_with_doubles = [[1, 2], [2, 3], [1, 2]]
```

using `uniq`:

```
array_with_doubles.uniq
# => [[1, 2], [2, 3]]
```

I want to find which values were removed.

Comment: You could simplify the wording by just asking which elements of the array are unique, unless you want answers to also show how to remove the unique elements from the array (in which case you should make that requirement clear).

Comment: The title and first sentence seem to be in conflict. I presume you want to identify the unique values and remove them, though the latter operation does not seem to be part of the question.

Answer (score 2):

You could try this:

```
 array_with_doubles.uniq.select { |x| array_with_doubles.count(x) > 1 }
```

Comment: This has the disadvantage that it is `O(n**2)` time complexity, compared to using `group_by` or a counting hash, which are `O(n)`. That's because `count` is `O(n)` and it has to be done for each element of the array. You can speed it up a bit by inserted `.uniq` before `.select`.

Answer (score 0):

Given the array above

```
array_with_doubles = [[1,2], [2,3], [1,2]]
```

Simply run the following to get the array values appearing more than once

```
array_with_doubles.group_by{|x|x}.map_values(&:size).select {|k,v| v>1}.keys
# => [[1,2]]
```

Comment: Hint: `.group_by(&:itself)`

Answer (score 0):

The unique elements can be determined as follows:

```
arr = [1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 4, 1]

uniq = arr.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) {|e,h| h[e] += 1}.select {|_,v| v == 1}.keys
  #=> [3, 4]
```

To remove the unique elements:

```
arr.reject { |e| uniq.include?(e) }
  #=> [1, 2, 2, 1, 1]
```

The nature of the objects in the array (numbers, arrays, hashes, instances, etc.) is not relevant to the question.

Determining the unique elements uses the form of [Hash::new](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Hash.html#method-c-new) that takes an argument (here zero), which is the value returned by `h[k]` if the hash `h` does not have a key `k`. Therefore, the expression `h[e] += 1`, which Ruby expands to

```
h[e] = h[e] + 1
```

before evaluating it, becomes

```
h[e] = 0 + 1
```

if `h` does not have a key `k`. This is sometimes called a *counting hash*.

Answer (score 0):

You can get all removed elements like this:

```
array_with_doubles = [[1, 2], [2, 3], [1, 2], [1, 2]]
require 'set'
array_with_doubles.each_with_object(Set.new).inject([]) { |a, (e, seen)|
  a << e if seen === e
  seen << e
  a
}
# => [[1, 2], [1, 2]]
```

Unlike most other answers, if an element would be removed twice by `uniq`, both copies of it are shown by this code. `uniq` retains the first equal element, while this code rejects the first equal element.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved above as below,

```
arr.inject([[],[]]) { |m, a| m[0].include?(a) ? m[1] << a : m[0] << a; m }[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option, one liner:

```
array_with_doubles = [[1, 2], [2, 3], [1, 2], [1, 2], [3, 5], [3, 5]]

array_with_doubles.uniq.each_with_object(array_with_doubles) { |e, a| a.delete_at(a.rindex(e)) }
# => [[1, 2], [1, 2], [3, 5]]
```

Comment: Updated after I noticed I duplicated a solution.